# changing height (feet and inches) to an integer in python pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains height information and I can't seem to figure out how to convert the somewhat unstructured information into an integer.

I figured the best way to approach this was to use regex but the main problem I'm having is that when I attempt to simplify a problem to use regex I usually take the first item in the dataframe (7 ' 5.5'') and try to use regex specifically on it.  It seemed impossible for me to put this data in a string because of the quotes.  So, I'm really confused on how to approach this problem.

here is my dataframe:

```
    HeightNoShoes   HeightShoes
0   7' 5.5"             NaN
1   6' 11"           7' 0.25"
2   6' 7.75"            6' 9"
3   6' 5.5"          6' 6.75"
4   5' 11"           6' 0"
```

Output should be in inches:

```
    HeightNoShoes   HeightShoes
0   89.5                NaN
1   83                 84.25
2   79.75               81
3   77.5              78.75
4   71                  72
```

My next option would be writing this to csv and using excel, but I would prefer to learn how to do it in python/pandas.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about using string.find() to locate the ' and the " and then cast and then do your conversion?  All that could be done within a function and passed to an Apply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The previous answer to the problem is a good solution to the problem without using regular expressions. I will post this in case you are curious about how to approach the problem using your first idea (using regexes).

It is possible to solve this using your approach of using a regular expression. In order to put the data you have (such as 7' 5.5") into a string in Python, you can escape the quote.

For example:

```
py_str = "7' 5.5\""
```

This, combined with a regular expression, will allow you to extract the information you need from the input data to calculate the output data. The input data consists of an integer (feet) followed by ', a space, and then a floating point number (inches). This float consists of one or more digits and then, optionally, a . and more digits. Here is a regular expression that can extract the feet and inches from the input data: `([0-9]+)' ([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)"`

The first group of the regex retrieves the feet and the second retrieves the inches. Here is an example of a function in python that returns a float, in inches, based on input data such as `"7' 5.5\""`, or NaN if there is no valid match:

Code:

```
r = re.compile(r"([0-9]+)' ([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\"")
def get_inches(el):
    m = r.match(el)
    if m == None:
        return float('NaN')
    else:
        return int(m.group(1))*12 + float(m.group(2))
```

Example:

```
>>> get_inches("7' 5.5\"")
89.5
```

You could apply that regular expression to the elements in the data. However, the solution of mapping your own function over the data works well. Thought you might want to see how you could approach this using your original idea.

Comment: Nice `regex` solution, but slightly more expensive. +1.

Answer (score 4):

One possible method without using `regex` is to write your own function and just `apply` it to the column/Series of your choosing.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
def parse_ht(ht):
    # format: 7' 0.0"
    ht_ = ht.split("' ")
    ft_ = float(ht_[0])
    in_ = float(ht_[1].replace("\"",""))
    return (12*ft_) + in_

print df["HeightNoShoes"].apply(lambda x:parse_ht(x))
```

Output:

```
0    89.50
1    83.00
2    79.75
3    77.50
4    71.00
Name: HeightNoShoes, dtype: float64
```

Not perfectly elegant, but it does the job with minimal fuss. Best of all, it's easy to tweak and understand.

Comparison versus the accepted solution:

```
In [9]: import re

In [10]: r = re.compile(r"([0-9]+)' ([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\"")
    ...: def get_inches2(el):
    ...:     m = r.match(el)
    ...:     if m == None:
    ...:         return float('NaN')
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return int(m.group(1))*12 + float(m.group(2))
    ...:     

In [11]: %timeit get_inches("7' 5.5\"")
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.51 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit parse_ht("7' 5.5\"")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 µs per loop
```

`parse_ht` is a little more than twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

**First create the dataframe of height values**

Let's first set up a Pandas dataframe to match the question. Then convert the values shown in feet and inches to a numerical value using **apply**.  NOTE: The questioner asks if the values can be converted to integers, however the first value in the 'HeightNoShoes' column is 7' 5.5" Since this string value is expressed in half inches, it will be converted first to a float value. Then you can use the **round** function to round it before typcasting the values as integers.

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd

# height data

no_shoes = ['''7' 5.5"''',
            '''6' 11"''',
            '''6' 7.75"''',
            '''6' 5.5" ''',
            '''5' 11"''']
shoes = [np.nan,
         '''7' 0.25"''',
         '''6' 9"''',
         '''6' 6.75"''',
         '''6' 0"''']

# put height data into a Pandas dataframe

height_data = pd.DataFrame({'HeightNoShoes':no_shoes, 'HeightShoes':shoes})
height_data.head()
```

[image]

**Next use a function to convert feet to float values**

Here is a function that converts feet and inches to a float value.

```
def feet_to_float(cell_string):
    try:
        split_strings = cell_string.replace('"','').replace("'",'').split()
        float_value = float(split_strings[0])+float(split_strings[1])
    except:
        float_value = np.nan
    return float_value
```

Next, apply the function to each column in the dataframe.

```
# obtain a copy of the height data
df = height_data.copy()

for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(feet_to_float)
df.head()
```

[image]

**Here is a function to convert float values to integer values with NaN values in the Pandas column**

If you would like to convert the dataframe to integer values with a NaN value in one column you can use the following function and code.  Note, that the function rounds the values first before typecasting them as integers. *Typecasting the float values as integers before rounding them will just truncate the values.*

```
def float_to_int(cell_value):
    try:
        return int(round(cell_value,0))
    except:
        return cell_value

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(feet_to_float)
```

Note: Pandas displays columns that contain both NaN values and integers as float values.

[image]

Here is the code to convert a single column in the dataframe to a numerical value.

```
df = height_data.copy()

df['HeightNoShoes'] = df['HeightNoShoes'].apply(feet_to_float)
df.head()
```

[image]

This is how to convert the single column of float values to integers. Note, that it's important to round the values first.  *Typecasting the values as integers before rounding them will incorrectly truncate the values.*

```
df['HeightNoShoes'] = round(df['HeightNoShoes'],0).astype(int)
df.head()
```

[image]

There are NaN values in the second Pandas column labeled **'HeightShoes'**.  Both the **feet_to_float** and **float_to_int** functions found above should be able to handle these.

```
df = height_data.copy()

df['HeightShoes'] = df['HeightShoes'].apply(feet_to_float)
df['HeightShoes'] = df['HeightShoes'].apply(float_to_int)
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may also serve the purpose

```
def inch_to_cm(x):
  if x is np.NaN:
    return x
  else:
    ft,inc = x.split("'")
    inches = inc[1:-1]
    return ((12*int(ft)) + int(inches)) * 2.54

df['Height'] = df['Height'].apply(inch_to_cm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `str.extract()`

```
(df.stack()
.str.extract(r"(\d+)' (\d+\.?\d*)")
.rename({0:'feet',1:'inches'},axis=1)
.astype(float)
.assign(feet = lambda x: x['feet'].mul(12))
.sum(axis=1)
.unstack())
```

or

```
(df.apply(
    lambda x: x.str.replace(r"(\d+)' ([0-9.]+)\"",
                            lambda x: str(int(x[1])*12 + float(x[2])),regex=True)
                            ))
```

Output:

```
   HeightNoShoes  HeightShoes
0          89.50          NaN
1          83.00        84.25
2          79.75        81.00
3          77.50        78.75
4          71.00        72.00
```